# How can I receive data from an HM10 on another Arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

[Link to set up of arduino's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyHXz.jpg) I am a beginner in things like the Arduino. I tried to set up a BLE HM10 connection between 2 Arduinos. I connected the BLE modules to my FTDI cable and set them as master and slave. They connect instantly when I power them up. I set the baud rate to 9600 (Default) and tried to send a "sensor value" from the slave to the master board where a servo should be moved.

I wrote my code down and tested it in many ways. The HM10 Rx/Tx pins in Arduino pin 0/1 and 7/8... nothing works for me. I wrote a statement that if the data of the slave reaches the master the serial terminal outputs nothing instead of "A".

**I used an Arduino Uno as slave with this code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); // RX, TX  
// Connect HM10      Arduino Uno
//     TXD          Pin 7
//     RXD          Pin 8

int reading = A0; // FSR attached to A0
int fsrreading;
int val;   

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);   //bluetooth serial begin
}

void loop() {
 int reading = analogRead(A0); //read fsr value
    Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
    Serial.println(reading);
    int val = map(reading, 0, 1023, 0, 180); // convert to servo value
    Serial.print("servo value = ");
    Serial.println(val);
    mySerial.write(val);//send fsr value to bt serial to the master
    delay(500); //Tweak this to lower value if communication is working
}
```

**And this is the code for the master on an Arduino Leonardo:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); // RX, TX
// Connect HM10      Arduino Uno
//     TXD          Pin 7
//     RXD          Pin 8
int servoPin = 9; //attached to pin 9 (PWM)
Servo myservo;

int val;
int data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);//bluetooth serial begin
  myservo.attach(servoPin);//servo obj is attached to pin9
}

void loop()
{
    int avail = mySerial.available();//check is serial is available
        if (avail > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < avail; i++)
            {
                int data = mySerial.read();
                //no need to map or constrain
                // data is already between 0 an 180
                myservo.write(data);//move servo to pos
                Serial.println(data,DEC);
                delay(50);
            }
        }
}
```

If I open up the serial terminal I just get the A and don't get any action if I press on the "sensor" (FSR)... I get the FSR value in the serial but not in the serial of the master... I don't know what the hell I did wrong.
Please guys, can you see through my spaghetti code and tell me my fault?

Comment: i think you are new to programming too. Your declaration shows that, It is not wrong to declare at multiple location but it is not a good practice. So please declare variable only at the top and remove all other declaration.

Comment: But this solution just clean up my code right ?

Comment: Yeah that was just for cleaning. And if you get A on your screen means that you failed to establish a connection between two arduino.

Comment: Can you tell me how to etablish the connection ? Or is it a general failure in my code besides the multi declaration?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code.and maybe with the FSR analog input.

Connect one end of FSR to 5V, the other end to Analog 0.
Then connect one end of a 10K resistor from Analog 0 to ground.

This way you will get a voltage between 0 volt(no pressure) and 4.9 volt(full pressure ~22lb) on the analog input.

This will result in a analog value between 0 and 1023.

mySerial.write(val) is sending an integer as byte, but a int value higher than 255 does not fit in byte, so garbage is send.
map your analog value before sending.
if you map it to value for your servo than no conversion is needed in the receiver.
so:

```
 int reading = analogRead(A0); //read fsr value
    Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
    Serial.println(reading);
    int val = map(reading, 0, 1023, 0, 180); // convert to servo value
    Serial.print("servo value = ");
    Serial.println(val);
    mySerial.write(val);//send fsr value to bt serial to the master
    delay(500); //Tweak this to lower value if communication is working
```

this line:

```
int val = mySerial.println(fsrreading); //convert fsr value in clean int
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. It maybe returns fsrreading length, but probable garbage and is not needed, so remove it.

In my example lines I set the delay to 500. The buffer of the HM10 can handle 20 bytes, 
so set the delay  as low as possible without overflowing the buffer.

In your receiving code you read only one byte.
To have a smooth servo motion you must read all available and handle all bytes to set the servo.
As you read all available there is no need to clean up Serial
and checking available after reading or cleaning will always print A in your sketch.

instead check for data received and print that, so you know what you receive.
Code:

```
void loop()
{
    int avail = mySerial.available();//check is serial is available
        if (avail > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < avail; i++)
            {
                int data = mySerial.read();
                //no need to map or constrain
                // data is already between 0 an 180
                myservo.write(data);//move servo to pos
                Serial.println(data,DEC);
                delay(50);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code you posted above, but I don't get any response in the serial terminal on the servo side. In the fsr-side I get the analog and mapped values, but I think there is no communication between the arduino's. The TX and RX on the FSR-side lights up but there is no light on the leonardo board but both BLE modules blink permanently. I have no clue how to check if there is a connection between those both. Is there something special i must set up between them except to the set them to the same baud rate and let them pair because this is already done.

Comment: Yes,
you have to setup a connection first. if a hm10 is blinking it means there is no connection.
Here is a link to a tutorial on how to setup a connection between 2 hm10 devices:
[link]http://www.martyncurrey.com/hm-10-bluetooth-4ble-modules/#HM-10%20-%20arduinoToArduino.
An important note: The tutorial is for the original Jinan Huamao firmware.
If you have a clone, than you have to google for the AT commands for your device.
To test your sketches you can setup a connection without the hm10 devices.
Connect softserial pins Rx and Tx from one board to Tx and Rx on the other board.

Comment: There is a connection between them. I paired them and if they power up they flash one time and than light up all the time. So I think there should be a valid connextion between both but it isn't working the way I want them to. I will wire the TX and RX pins directly to the other board and see what will happen. Must I change something in the code for this ? Or will it also work with my personal set up serial myserial?

Comment: There is no need to change your sketches if you use soft-serial on both for linking them together.
Use hardware serial for program uploading and serial monitor.
Don`t forget to connect the grounds of the two boards together. 
Once you know your sketches are working you can troubleshoot your BLE-connection.
Let me know how things are progressing or not.

Comment: I tried to do it with the soft serial and hardware serial but i didn't get any response on the servo side. I posted a link to picture of my setup in hardware serial in my first post. Maybe someone can have an eye on it to see if i wired something wrong?

Comment: Use the softserial for this, because that is the way you send and receive the servo commands.
Edit your original question and show us the code you are currently using so we can see if there is a issue with it.
Your wiring seems to be OK, except for the fact that you use hardware serial.

Comment: I updated the original post with the latest code i use. I hope we can solve my problem soon ^^ I so happy that you try to help me making this work. Thank you!

Comment: It is better if you move your issue to the Arduino section of Stack Exchange, this more about Arduino than Ble_LE.
Your code seems to be fine, except for the global and in-line declarations. 
I don`t think this is an issue for the compiler, but not good practice.
 I cannot test your setup, don`t have the same hardware.

Comment: I just found in the SoftwareSerial library reference that there is a limitation for Arduino Leonardo:
Not all pins on the Leonardo and Micro support change interrupts,
so only the following can be used for RX: 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI). 
Maybe this is your problem.